# Mysql syntax error when trying to update a table in a joomla plugin

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this query for a joomla plugin

```
$query = "UPDATE #__content SET fulltext='$_POST[statenames]' WHERE id=$articleId";
```

But it gives error -

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'fulltext = '1' WHERE id = 41' at line 1 SQL=UPDATE jst_content
>   SET fulltext = '1' WHERE id = 41

What is the error?

Comment: Do you have a column named `fulltext`? This is a reserved keyword.

Comment: As @ypercube stated `fulltext` is a reserved keyword so surround it with [backticks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Thanks ypercube and SaschaM78. Its working after adding backticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FULLTEXT` is a MySQL Reserved Keyword. You must wrap the column with backtick.

```
$query = "UPDATE #__content SET `fulltext` = '$_POST[statenames]' WHERE id=$articleId";
```

- [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` if the value of the variable(s) came from clients. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using PreparedStatements you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)